# Unable to delete EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am unable to delete an amazon EBS volume that i no longer use. It's a 100GB volume and the options to detach, force detach and delete are all disabled. I cannot find a way to delete this volume. Is this a bug within the aws amazon panel ?

Comment: Make sure you have clicked on the checkbox that appears in the first column in the AWS console and if you still see the buttons are disabled, then I would contact the support and get it fixed if you think the buttons are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the EBS volume is not in any where in use somehow which might have it locked down. This happened to me once and after I went in to panel after a while I was able to see it back .